# How to create a div with border and radius only at the bottom, inside another div with border and radius

Tags: html, css

I need a component that have a box wit `border` and `border-radius` and inside this component i need a header with `border`*and `border-radius` at bottom.

I write this fiddle to better understand:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alerusso/8zrko03n/2/)

The code:

```css
border-1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

border-2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<border-1>
  <border-2>

  </border-2>
</border-1>
```

Expected result:

[image: Expected result:]

But some time i get this when add some padding or appear the scroll bar:

[image]

Can someone explain me why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your changed [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alerusso/8zrko03n/2/).

You just need to change `border:1px solid black;` to `border-bottom:1px solid black;` so that you border is only on the bottom.

Result looks like this:

[image: Result]

Here is the full css of border 2:

```
border-2 {
  flex:1 1 auto;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

```css
border-1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

border-2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<border-1>
  <border-2>

  </border-2>
</border-1>
```

Comment: Can you explain me why i have strange behaviour when i have all the border?

Comment: It's because of the position of the two elements. That's why you see both borders.

Comment: Yes but the main problem solved is that sometimes appear a line between borders.

Answer (score 2):

Use `position:relative` to parent and `position:absolute` to child

Also add to child `width:calc(100% - 2px);` (`-2px` : `1px` for border right `+` `1px` for border left )

```css
border-1 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    margin:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:flex;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position:relative;
}

border-2 {
  flex:1 1 auto;
  border:1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  position:absolute;
  width:calc(100% - 2px);
}
```

```html
<border-1>
  <border-2>
    
  </border-2>
</border-1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you will find it useful!

```css
.outer{
width:300px;
border-radius:10px;
border:4px solid #000;
background-color:green;
height:200px;
}
.outer .inner{
max-width:100%;
border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
border:4px solid #000;
background-color:red;
height:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```